# Multi Server Query generating Login failures

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

My problem is that when using multi server queries using SSMS from SQL Server 2008 R2 against SQL Server 2008 R2, 2005 and 2000 I occasionally get error messages such as:

SQL Server 2008R2

> Login failed for user 'DomainName\ADName'. Reason: Failed to open the
>   explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: 21.12.0.0]
>   Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.

SQL Server 2005

> 2013-10-10 15:55:34.28 logon     Login failed for user
>   'DomainName\ADName'.
>   Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 16.

SQL Server 2000

> Login failed for user 'DomainName\ADName'. [CLIENT: 21.12.0.0]

Now my query works fine but given what my query does is search for errors in logs it is not ideal that it should also generate such errors.

My methodology may be flawed, what I have done is create a group under Local Server Groups and registered a few dozen servers of various versions. Then I right click on this group, select New Query to open a new batch window. Lastly I open my saved script and run it. In rough outline this is what it does

```
use master
go
determine version of SQL as like '%8.0%' or not
create temporary table based on version and pump results of xp_readerrorlog 0-6 into it
translate temporary table to another and insert to results temporary table
select on results table
drop temporary tables
go
```

I am a sysadmin on all machines. Two things I tried was the 'use master' statement at the top of the script and changing the registered servers to have a "Connect to database" of master. Neither of these has eliminated the problem. Does anyone have any further suggestions?

Comment: have you checked the sql server error logs on the server that's throwing the failure?

Comment: @Paul What is the default database for the login you are trying to use ?

Comment: @swasheck I thought that was what I quoted in the original question? Have I glossed over something?

Comment: @Kin on each server in question there is a Login named Admins. This is an AD group to which I am a member. That Login is a sysadmin with a default database of master in each case.

Comment: @Paul sorry, i wasn't clear and didn't ask the correct question. where did you get that error? did you get an error state/severity?

Comment: @swasheck the errors occur in "SQL Server Logs". What I have done is only quoted 1 line of the error, I will amend to include the state/severity information.

Comment: @Paul sorry. that was not at all clear from the original question. and you're only working in `master`, right?

Comment: @swasheck How to answer that.. lets say I both expect and intend to be only working in master. I could post my full code if desired but it doesn't do anything more than the pseudo code already indicates. It's just "exec xp_readerrorlog" then playing with temporary tables and ways I wish to display things.

Comment: @paul its very strange, but out of curiosity any database set to autoclose **by mistake** ? Else a profiler trace while you are running your query will tell you the offender.

Comment: in addition to autoclosed dbs, have you tried sp_readerrorlog to rule out any potential snag with XPs?

Comment: @Kin I just checked every DB on a SQL2008R2 machine (that had this error) and no DB (system or user) has autoclose set to true. Additionally most of our DBs are internally developed and I would not expect any developer to use this setting.

Comment: @swasheck No I have not. It may be I need to investigate that SP and try to use it tomorrow. One more nugget, if I press Execute a 2nd time on the query the error is not generated a second time. Indeed closing SSMS and starting again does not regenerate the error. I have had this error 3-4 times however. Perhaps following reboot, but of PC or server I'm not sure. Won't have time to check PC reboot until tomorrow and server reboot is a bit more tricky.

Comment: @paul we have told you what might be the issue. And you confirmed that **everything** is configured/checked OK. As we cant access (and we dont want), the only way to find out is **running a PROFILER**. This article will help you (http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2581/sql-server-error-18456-finding-the-missing-databases/) choosing the events. That should solve your issue.

Comment: If you have not yet used Profiler to find your problem, perhaps this post from Phil Brammer will help you know what to trace: http://www.ssistalk.com/2011/05/06/quick-tip-error-18456-severity-14-state-38/

Comment: Thanks. It's going to take me several days to lock this down at least. Today for example I'm repeating my process without change to see if I can even predict a server it will occur on.